# Transação com Entitiframework 6.1.3 e PostgresSql não funciona corretamente

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando utilizar EntityFramework6.Npgsqlcom transação, contudo obtenho uma exception quando chamo o método DbContext.UseTransaction e passo uma transação.

**Mensagem de erro (Último InnerException):**

> "Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 25P02: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block\r\n   em Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.

Assim criei um projeto para simular e tentar encontrar o real problema:

**Projeto Teste**

```
[Route("")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var conn = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["app:pgconn"]))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
                {
                    using (var ctx = new CadastrosContext(conn))
                    {
                        var tenant = new Tenant();



                        ctx.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);

                        ctx.Tenants.Add(tenant);
                        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);

                        Debug.WriteLine($"Tenant 1 Id: {tenant.TenantId}");
                    }

                    using (var ctx = new CadastrosContext(conn))
                    {
                        var tenant = new Tenant();



                        ctx.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);

                        ctx.Tenants.Add(tenant);
                        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync()
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);

                        Debug.WriteLine($"Tenant 2 Id: {tenant.TenantId}");
                    }

                    await transaction.CommitAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }


        return Ok();
    }
```

**Pacotes utilizados**

> package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net462"
>   
>   package id="EntityFramework6.Npgsql" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net462" 
>   
>   package id="Npgsql" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net462"

O mais estranho é que na segunda chamada do método, tudo ocorre normalmente.
Após algumas horas investigando o problema (utilizando outras bases de dados funciona normalmente), encontrei que, ao alterar a versão utilizada do EntityFramework), o projeto volta a funcionar normalmente.

**Pacotes que funcionam**

> package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net462"
>   
>   package id="EntityFramework6.Npgsql" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net462" 
>   
>   package id="Npgsql" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net462"

Alguém mais teve este problema?? 
Será que existe algum bug no Npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql que não suporte a última versão do EntityFramework (6.1.3)?